# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - using glob

Tags: php, foreach, warnings

Today i have a problem with my script, my script should search for (.css files)

I've used a code to:

1. Search for all subfolders in a root folder
2. Make all paths of subfolders in an array
3. by using foreach(){glob....}, the script should found all paths of css files

Here is my code :

```
$path = '';
$stack[] = $dir;

while ($stack) {
    $thisdir = array_pop($stack);

    if ($dircont = scandir($thisdir)) {
        $i=0;

        while (isset($dircont[$i])) {
            if ($dircont[$i] !== '.' && $dircont[$i] !== '..') {
                $current_file = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";

                if (is_dir($current_file)) {
                    $path[] = "{$thisdir}/{$dircont[$i]}";
                    $stack[] = $current_file;
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

$path[] = $dir;
foreach($path as $dirname){
    $add = glob($dirname . '/*.css');

    foreach($add as $file){
        $code = file_get_contents($file);
        $code_arab = arabicer($code);
        file_put_contents($file,$code_arab);
    }
}
```

When i start my script i found an waning message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u274517531/public_html/libs/functions.php on line 131

I'm sure my array is not empty.

So, anyone can help me how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$path[] = $dir;
foreach($path as $dirname){
    $add = glob($dirname . '/*.css');
    foreach($add as $file){
```

to this:

```
$path[] = $dir;
var_dump($path);
foreach($path as $dirname){
    $add = glob($dirname . '/*.css');
    var_dump($add);
    foreach($add as $file){
```

We don't know which line 131 is, so I don't know which foreach fails.

(I'm guessing the 2nd, because the first is practically forced to array by `$path[] = ..`)

Comment: Thanks for answering , i did ==> the first array $path[] is get this info --> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "../uploads/newtest/newtest" [1]=> string(55) "../uploads/newtest/newtest/newtest - Copy - Copy - Copy" [2]=> string(18) "../uploads/newtest" }  |||| the second array $add[] returned this info --> bool(false) || line 131 now be #139 and its the second foreach

Comment: So you know the problem and its solution now right? `$dirname` is not a (readable) dir or something. The `glob` fails. `var_dump($dirname)` to be sure. `var_dump` is your very bestest friend. PHP = debugging

Comment: I tried var_dump($dirname); , it get to me the dirs name , it works, the problem in $add , i dont know why the script can't find the CSS files, im sure there is a css file in the dir (/uploads/newtest/newtest/newtest - Copy - Copy - Copy) , do you have any info how to make glob() works ?

Comment: If `$dirname` is a readable dir, it doesn't matter how many `.css` files there are: it should always return an array. Response when I try `var_dump(glob('/SERVER/*.css'));` locally: `array(0) {
}`. What does `var_dump($dirname)` print **literally**?

Comment: string(23) "uploads/newtest/newtest" === NEXT LINE ===
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u274517531/public_html/libs/functions.php on line 141 === NEXT LINE ===
string(52) "uploads/newtest/newtest/newtest - Copy - Copy - Copy" ==== NEXT LINE ===
string(15) "uploads/newtest" =================================================== line 141 content is : foreach($add as $file){

Comment: Maybe it's because the path doesn't start with a `/` although that shouldn't matter. Doesn't `glob` throw an error/warning? Is error reporting on? Put this above all else in the script: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Comment: Great, i tried to make var_dump($add) inside the path foreach,, the path array have 3 folders .. one of the 3 have css file inside it,, when i start my script,, the 2 dirs which dont have css file inside,, returned an error (Invalid argument supplied for foreach()) but the other dir which have css file inside it, didn't returns any errors ,,, i will try to fix my script because i found the error place ==> thank you very much for your answers and im sorry for my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You say you are sure that your array is not empty, but what the *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()* error message means is that it is **not even an array**. Try it youself if you don't believe it:

```
var_dump($add);
```

Most likely, there was an error finding files and [glob()](http://es.php.net/glob) is returning `FALSE`:

> Returns an array containing the
>   matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on
>   error.

Comment: check my comment on the answer #2 :)

Comment: That's right , but the problem is how can i make the function glob() works ? im sure there is a css file in the directories . Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with a PHP script today and it took switching from a foreach loop to a for loop to fix it. Not sure what means, the array looks and works the same.

```php
// Errors out
$files = glob($directory.'*.html');
foreach($files as $file){
    echo($file);
}

// No error
$files = glob($directory.'*.html');
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
    echo($files[$i]);
}
```