# Foreach loop to loop for each file in a directory not working

Tags: php, foreach

I am making a foreach loop to run some code for each file in the directory. Can someone help me debug this loop? Problem is: I always get a warning causing this loop not to work.

This is my code:

```
$files = glob("data/*.txt");
foreach($files as $file) {
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
}
```

Comment: _I always get a warning_ Please share the error message with us.

Comment: `I always get a warning` - and that is what?

Comment: @Jonny Mopp The message is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: Also, the problem is with the for loop, not anything else.

Comment: @user10693192 Does the data folder exist? And is it in the same folder of the script?

Comment: [Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - using glob](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5927118)

Comment: Please check if `is_dir('data')` and `is_writable('data')`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php  As others stated the folder may not exist, is writable should tell you if PHP has write permissions for that location as well.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the dupe? Check the value of `$files` with `var_dump($files);`. What does that report?